# undefined reference to `Cat::Grizzly()'|

Tags: c++, eclipse, class, codeblocks, undefined-reference

so I just started learning C++ literally yesterday and thanks to some prior experience with Lua I'm catching on pretty fast. I've been doing a beginner course on it at http://courses.caveofprogramming.com/. I was trying to create a     class but ran into an error.It might also be worth mentioning that the expert uses Eclipse as his EDI, while I use CodeBlocks. Here's what I have.

main.cpp

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include "Cat.h"

 using namespace std;

 int main()
 {
     Cat tommy;
     tommy.Grizzly() == true;
     tommy.Bark();

     return 0;
 }
```

Cat.cpp

```
#include "Cat.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void Cat::Bark()
{
    if (Grizzly())
    {
        cout << "RUFF!!!!!!" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << ":)" << endl;
    }
}
```

Cat.h

```
#ifndef CAT_H
#define CAT_H


class Cat
{
public :
    bool Grizzly();
    void Bark();
};

#endif // CAT_H
```

here's the error

```
C:\Users\Nas\Desktop\Coding Projects\Class Members 4\main.cpp|9|undefined reference to `Cat::Grizzly()'|
```

Comment: A comparison like `tommy.Grizzly() == true;` won't accomplish much in Lua either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get an `undefined reference` error because you haven't defined `Cat::Grizzly`, you have just declared it.

Add a definition for the function:

```
bool Cat::Grizzly() {
    //implementation
}
```